# UDP socket slowness

Tags: python, sockets, udp

We are listening to stocks snapshot data through UDP multicast. However there seems to be a limit with the speed with which sockets can receive the data.

```
while 1:
    start1 = time.clock()
    SocketData = Msocket.recv(4096)
    end1 = time.clock()
    counter += 1
```

I created a scheduler which runs every 1 seconds and counts the number of `data` being received, which ranges from 100-300 but not more. I have a recorded feed from which I can throw thousands of bursts per second but it won't respond accordingly peaking with below rates

```
175
172
190
```

Is there a throughput limit for this socket? Also no packets drops are being shown. Should I used different configuration?

Below is the configuration being used.

```
def prepare(self):
    self.BroadCastSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
                                socket.SOCK_DGRAM,
                                socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    self.BroadCastGroup = socket.inet_aton(self.MCAST_ADDR)
    self.InterfaceIp = socket.inet_aton(self.MCAST_IP)
    self.MultiCastRequest = struct.pack('=4s4s',
                               self.BroadCastGroup,
                               self.InterfaceIp)
    self.BroadCastSocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP,
                           socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP,
                           self.MultiCastRequest)
    self.BroadCastSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,
                           socket.SO_REUSEADDR,
                           1)

def bind(self):
    self.BroadCastSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', self.MCAST_PORT))
```

Comment: Write a simple C or C++ program that does the same thing and run it on the same machine.  Does it perform better?

Comment: `self.BroadCastSocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', self.MCAST_PORT))` Don't use all interfaces.  **Cannot be connected to a broadcasting socket !**  It is a weird idea to respond to the municipal announcement (o: .